# Setting up a function to find the product of two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to set up my spreadsheet to calculate the product (column K) by multiplying the price of an item (column I) by the quantity purchased (column J).

i.e.
every price point in column 'I' to be multiplied by every quantity in column 'J' and the total to be given in column 'K'

or

I*J=K
5.99 * 1 = 5.99
1.99 * 2 = 3.98
etc

Answer (score 3):

You've almost written the required formula already. If you put the formula:

=I1*J1

... into cell `K1`, and if you've got `5.99` in cell `I1` and `1` in `J1`, then `5.99` will appear in cell `K1`. If you Copy and Paste cell `K1` into cells `K2` and below, the same computation can be done as far down column K as you would like.

You'll probably make quicker progress if you press the F1 key in Excel, then type "Formula" into the Help search box and select "Create a formula". The Help system will guide you through learning how to write formulas.

Comment: +1 for "The Help system will guides you through learning how to write formulas."

Comment: @B.Shelton: If this is the answer you need, could you click on the tick mark to accept and close this question? Thanks. Glad to help.